# Why do scoped enums allow use of | operator when initializing using previously assigned values?

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer, bitwise-operators

I'm converting unscoped enumerations to scoped enumerations, and have run across a puzzle.

Stroustrup, *C++ Programming Language*, 4th edition, Section 8.4.1, documents that scoped enum classes are not implicitly converted to integral types, and provides code for operators `|` and `&` as an example of how to use `static_cast` to work around that.

Shouldn't the following initialization using the `|` operator on previously defined `enum` values be illegal?

```
enum class FileCopy {
    PreviousHDUs   = 1,
    CurrentHDU     = 2,
    FollowingHDUs  = 4,
    AllHDUs        = PreviousHDUs | CurrentHDU | FollowingHDUs,
    CurrentHeader  = 8
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << static_cast<int>( FileCopy::AllHDUs) << "\n";
}
```

I've tested this on Wandbox using both clang & gcc HEAD with `--pedantic-errors`, and it compiles and returns the expected output, `7`.  That's not to say it's legal, just that it seems to be accepted by the compilers.

Is this explicitly documented behavior?  I've been unable to parse the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) in a way that describes this behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[dcl.enum]/5:

> ... If the underlying type is fixed, the type of each enumerator prior to the closing brace is the underlying type ...

That is, each enumerator has type `int` until the closing brace is encountered. After that point, the enumerators have type `FileCopy` and you would not be able to bitwise-OR them together like this anymore.

Comment: And this also allows you to use other arithmetic operations, e.g. `enum class { A, B = A + 2 };`

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the language I needed to see.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C++17 Standard (8.5.13 Bitwise inclusive OR operator)

> 1 The usual arithmetic conversions (8.3) are performed; the result is
>   the bitwise inclusive OR function of its operands. The operator
>   applies only to integral or unscoped enumeration operands.

And (10.2 Enumeration declarations)

> 5. ... **For a scoped enumeration type, the underlying type is int if it is not 
>      explicitly specified. In both of these cases, the underlying
>      type is said to be fixed.** Following the closing brace of an
>      enum-specifier, each enumerator has the type of its enumeration. **If
>      the underlying type is fixed, the type of each enumerator prior to the
>      closing brace is the underlying type** and the constant-expression in
>      the enumerator-definition shall be a converted constant expression of
>      the underlying type

So this is explicitly documented behavior.

Comment: I think within the scoped enum definition, while the type is still incomplete, the elements may have integral type.

Comment: @Demolishun Thanks. It is a typo.:)

Comment: @VladFromMoscow Thanks!